# association in cakephp for multidimensional

Tags: sql, cakephp, associations

i am newbie to cakephp. I need to use assoc for 3 tables I want result to be in following way

```
 `[0] => Array
    (
     [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 45
                [email] => nonita@gmail.com
            )           
  [Product] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [user_id] => 45

                [description] => wegjhj
            )

        [Comment] => Array
            (
               [0] => Array
                     (
                       [id] => 1
                       [comment] => 'kjfkjfkfd'
                       [product_id] => 5
                      )
                [1] => Array
                     (
                       [id] => 2
                       [comment] => 'kjfkjfkfd'
                       [product_id] => 5
                      )
           )
    )
 )`
```

how can I create assoc in cakephp and is it possible to create array like this using assoc?
i want to fetch user name , product name and the comment that user has given on the product

Comment: try ```$this->Product->find('all');```

Comment: try `$this->Users->find('all', ['contain' =>['Products' => ['Comments']]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Product model bind the model to User Model as `belongsTo` association

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    "User" => array(
        "className" => "User",
        "foreignKey" => "user_id"
    )
);
```

and to Comment Model as `hasMany` association

```
$public $hasMany = array(
    "Comment" => array(
        "className" => "Comment",
        "foreignKey" => "product_id"
    )
);
```

and run the `find` query on Product Model as

```
$this->Product->find('all');
```